# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule tow conditions?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a slight problem figuring out what I am doing wrong. I have a site where I only have https for two different urls - www.example.de and example.de. I also however have subdomains specified - x.example.de and y.example.de (that are being used from a different domain name altogether, in case that's relevant).

So I tried following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =^(example.de|www.example.de)  [NC]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(x|y)\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I was unsuccessful with everything I tried, in particular both RewriteConds above; in the code above for instance it changes http to https even if it is x or y subdomain. Can someone PLEASE HELP? Thank you!

Comment: there was another line in the code that is not being displayed - here it is
</IfModule>

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a few days... Yes, they all use the same htaccess file. Thanks for the help with displaying my code properly :-)

Comment: I think I managed :-) 

the second condition is this  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.de|www.example.de)  [NC]    

This seems to work beatifully! Thank you all for your help!